# Visual Studio 2012 include paths do not match the command line

Tags: visual-studio-2012, include, directx, include-path

In short, the command line passed to CL does not match the project properties, and I do not have an override on the command line.

I'm trying to compile a DX11 project, and have the include path set to include, for all projects and configurations:

```
$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include
```

However, the DXUT11Lib project does not compile.  If I look at the command line output, the only include passed to the command line is:

```
cl /c /IC:\Users\Dave\Source\SVN\DXFireworks\DXUT11Lib\DXUT11Lib\Core [...other options]
```

That 'Core' folder is not among the options in the config dialog, and the ones in the config dialog aren't there (the DXSDK being the obvious one).

How could it be that the properties dialog include paths are not making it to the command line?  I'm as certain as I can be that I'm looking at the same configuration (Win32, All).

In fact, if I set the VC++ Include Directories to "BANANA" the command line is still:

```
cl /c /IC:\Users\Dave\Source\SVN\DXFireworks\DXUT11Lib\DXUT11Lib\Core /ZI
/nologo- /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm
/EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yc"dxut.h"
/Fp"C:\Users\Dave\Source\SVN\DXFireworks\Debug\dxut11lib.pch" /Fo"Debug\\"
/Fd"C:\Users\Dave\Source\SVN\DXFireworks\Debug\dxut11lib.pdb" /Gd /TP
/showIncludes /analyze- /errorReport:prompt Core\DXUT.cpp
```

The word "BANANA" never makes it!  I've cleaned, deleted the sdf file, all about out of ideas.

Furthermore, if I go to the 'Command Line' property page I see that the 'predicted' command line is the following, which does not match what I see with the startup banner suppressed:

```
/Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t
/I"C:\Users\Dave\Source\SVN\DXFireworks\DXUT11Lib\DXUT11Lib\Core"
/I"E:\SDK\DX9SDK\Include\Include" /Zi /Gm- /O2
/Fd"C:\Users\Dave\Source\SVN\DXFireworks\Release\dxut11lib.pdb" /fp:precise
/D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX-
/Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\"
/Fp"Release\DXUT11Lib.pch"
```

Comment: Note the latest version of DXUT11 is on [CodePlex & GitHub](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437), and does not require the legacy DirectX SDK at all to build. If your project only uses Direct3D 11, I strongly recommend moving to this version and removing all use of the deprecated D3DX11 library (see [Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Visual Studio 2012 [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855621(v=vs.110).aspx), the include directory project property corresponds to the INCLUDE environment variable:

> #### Include Directories
>
> Directories in which to search for include files that are referenced in the
> source code. Corresponds to the **INCLUDE** environment variable.

So presumably the include directories are passed in the INCLUDE environment variable and not as command line arguments.